# More than one index/type in Elasticsearch?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

Following the documentation's canonical example, say I want to store tweets in elasticsearch, but I want to specify an endpoint that handles more than two fields, e.g.

```
/tweets/some_twitter_handle/some_month/tweet/id
```

In this example, I want to index on `tweets`, but also on `some_twitter_handle` and `some_month`, with `tweet` type, and some `id`.

Is this possible, or is the only possible mapping something akin to what they provide, with one `index` and one `type`, e.g `/tweets/tweet/id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index/type/id is what determines which shard a document ends up on (in the absense of other routing information).  Elasticsearch indexes every field by default (you can control this through a mapping if you don't want some of your field indexed).  So by putting a `"twitter_handle": "whatever"` into the document, it becomes searchable by that "twitter_handle".

Comment: Cool. I'm kind of new to this; is searching for a twitter handle with the mapping `/tweets/tweet/id` (where `tweet` would house a `twitter_handle`) more computationally expensive than having the mapping:

`/tweets/twitter_handle/id`? That's mostly my concern.

Comment: `/tweets/tweet/id` would be a specific twitter message.  If you were to try to put all of a specific person's tweets into a single document (ie if `id` were a twitter handle), it would be very inefficient.

Comment: `/tweets/twitter_handle/id` would still be a single twitter message, but in the former example, the `twitter_handle` would be a field in the tweet, whereas in the latter, it's just a more specific routing.

Comment: The mapping for any given document in ES is based on its index and type.  So using twitter_handle as a type makes it awkward to create a mapping that applies to all tweets.  You would have to create a mapping template to make sure all of your types were right.